# Gstreamer fluid rtp (MPEG2 TS) playback

Tags: video, video-streaming, gstreamer

I have read about gstreamer support for rtp and it should be possible to play rtp streams with gstreamer.

I've tried with this

```
GST_DEBUG="*:3" gst-launch-0.10 -v udpsrc buffer-size="5000"   \
port=1234 multicast-group="239.0.0.17"   \
caps="application/x-rtp,media=(string)video,clock-rate=(int)90000,encoding-name=(string)H264"   \
! .recv_rtp_sink_0 gstrtpbin ! rtpmp2tdepay   \
! mpegtsdemux ! ffdec_h264 ! xvimagesink
```

and I get video to display, but completely unwatchable - one frame per 3 seconds (and that frame doesn't look normal at all)

Does anyone know how to make gstreamer to play rtp streams that are in MPEG2 TS? In that format I receive satellite channels from IPTV so it should be common.

Comment: shouldn't you use ffdec_mpeg2video instead of ffdec_h264?

Comment: no, I think that mpeg2 ts is just a container because ffdec_mpeg2video returns no picture at all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've managed to solve this:

```
gst-launch-0.10 -vm udpsrc port=1234 multicast-group=239.0.0.1 \
caps="application/x-rtp,media=(string)video,clock-rate=(int)90000,payload=(int)96" \
! .recv_rtp_sink_0 gstrtpbin latency=800 ! rtpmp2tdepay \
! tsdemux ! ffdec_h264 ! xvimagesink
```

and it works great.

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 0):

Why are you using such a small buffer on the udpsrc? Was the default not good? Also check back on irc, there was/is some trouble with the mpegtsdemuxer.

Comment: I've tried without any buffer (default) but nothing changed... also with bigger buffer there is no change - probably the pipeline is not good. Does it mean that Gstreamer is not capable of playing streams that are DVB-S(2) (or T) standard? I'll try to find more information about that.

Comment: @10robinho regarding your last question, I have been successfully able to play dvb-s streams, but they were udp. I do not know devices which stream dvb-s ts using rtp.

Comment: @Wimmel - can you tell me your pipeline for that? That is how I get streams form multicast network.

Comment: @10robinho It seems the situation previously was a bit different different, but I was just able to play video. I'll post it as an answer

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example where I can play a dvb-s (mpeg2) video from a multicast, multiprogram transport stream:

```
gst-launch -v udpsrc port=1234 multicast-group="239.255.219.99" ! queue2 ! mpegtsdemux program-number=2004 ! queue2 ! ffdec_mpeg2video ! autovideosink
```

If I don't add the queue's before and after the tsdemux, I get similar problems as you describe, so that might be your problem too.

Comment: I've managed to simulate your enviroment by swithching to udp streaming. `gst-launch-0.10 -v udpsrc port=1234 multicast-group="239.0.0.1" ! queue2 ! mpegtsdemux program-number=101 ! queue2 ! ffdec_mpeg2video ! autovideosink` where program-number=101 is PID (video stream ID). I didn't manage to get any picture, here is the output [link](http://pastebin.com/TfRrWf5X). It says `default gstutils.c:2037:gst_element_link_pads_filtered: Could not link pads: mpegtsdemux0:(null) - queue0:(null)`

Comment: If I don't use program-number=101, gstreamer manages to link pads, but I get a bunch of `mpegtsdemux gstmpegtsdemux.c:1289:gst_mpegts_demux_data_cb:<mpegtsdemux0> looks like we have a corrupt packet because its timestamp is buggered timestamp: 3:05:34.937022222 compared to last timestamp: 0:00:00.008904441` and similar errors

Comment: It is possible you do have rtp. Then you should just modify your original command to include a queue2 before and after the mpegtsdemux. But if that does not help I can't help you.

Comment: I tried, it is a bit better, but still far from watchable video :( Thanks anyways